# Posting input data to database in Wordpress with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Currently I have 2 inputs that don't use `<form>` tags:

```js
function checkSubmit() {
    var userInfo = {
        'moneyOf': document.getElementById('priceSlider').value,
        'emailOf': document.getElementById('inputheaderBox').value
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        data: {
            action: "savedata", userInfo
        },               
        success: function(data){
            //alert('success');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input id="priceSlider" type="range" min="100000" value="200000" max="1000000" step="1000" />
    <input type="text" id="inputheaderBox"/>
    <button id="inputSubmit" onClick="checkSubmit()">Submit</button></form>
```

Doesn't seem to work

Comment: Change ----------- url: 'admin-ajax.php'

Comment: Still 404 @Mittal

Comment: Check the network tab, URL is correct?

Comment: so, what is your error? you get `404 error` on Ajax request?

Comment: I am ok with @Mittal, url should be `url : admin-ajax.php` BUT is this .php in the same folder that your .js script? Do you still have 404 if you add path/to/your/file.php in the url?

Answer (score 0):

Your function placed in JS file? JS cannot render and interpreter PHP code.

See [AJAX reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). You should include your script using `wp_enqueue_script()` and define ajax url with `wp_localize_script()`.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', PATH_TO_JS_FOLDER . 'custom.js', [ 'jquery' ], null, true );
wp_localize_script( 'custom', 'ajax_params', [
        'url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    ] );
```

And inside your script:

`url: ajax_params.url`,

See reference. You will understood what i mean.

Comment: How did you know that js codes are in js file? Could be in header :P

Comment: @RobStark wp_localize_script(“frontJS”, “ajax_parama”, array(“url”=>admin_url(“admin-ajax.php”));